# com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: HostKey has been changed:

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I'm trying to establish a SSH connection in Java which is running on a docker container. The container is spun up using docker-compose on which I mount the ssh folder. The code produces the following exception:

```
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException: HostKey has been changed:[192.xx.xx.xx]:<port number other than 22>
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.checkHost(Session.java:794)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:348)
at com.jcraft.jsch.Session.connect(Session.java:186)
```

The ssh folder is mounted like this:

```
volumes:
      - '/home/myusername/.ssh/:/root/.ssh'
```

I have set the KnownHosts and added identity.
I have tried removing the known_hosts file. Then ssh into the machine from the terminal successfully which re-adds the host back into known_hosts. I have also added the keys manually using:

```
ssh-keyscan -t rsa,ecdsa 192.xx.xx.xx >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

but no luck so far.
I have included my code snippet:

```
import com.jcraft.jsch.JSch;
import com.jcraft.jsch.Session;

public class ssh {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        try {
            JSch jsch = new JSch();
            jsch.setKnownHosts("/root/.ssh/known_hosts");
    
            jsch.addIdentity("/root/.ssh/id_rsa");            
           
            Session session = jsch.getSession(user, host, port);
            session.setConfig("PreferredAuthentications", "publickey");
            session.connect();

        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
.....
}
```

I should also add, I do not want to set StrictHostKeyChecking to "no" which many have pointed is not safe.

Ok, I should edit my question a little bit. The program is running on a docker container and I have mounted the ssh folder in docker-compose like this:

```
volumes:
      - '/home/myusername/.ssh/:/root/.ssh'
```

Then I set the known hosts like this:

```
jsch.setKnownHosts("/root/.ssh/known_hosts");
```

I also set the ssh config file with the same path in the code and get the host, port from it and that works:

```
 ConfigRepository configRepository =
                    com.jcraft.jsch.OpenSSHConfig.parseFile("/root/.ssh/config");
            String host = configRepository.getConfig(hostAlias).getHostname();
            int port = configRepository.getConfig(hostAlias).getPort();
    System.out.println(host);
    System.out.println(port);
```

Comment: Try fully pathing `jsch.setKnownHosts("~/.ssh/known_hosts");`

Comment: What does the `known_hosts` generated by `ssh` look like? What is the full JSch error message? It's server's *public* key, no need to hide it from us.

Comment: Ok, I should edit my question a little bit. The program is running on a docker container and I have mounted the ssh folder in docker-compose like: 
```
volumes:
      - '/home/nuclera/.ssh/:/root/.ssh'

Comment: That does not answer my question about contents/format of your `known_hosts` file. + I do not see *"port number other than 22"* in your `ssh-keyscan -t rsa,ecdsa 192.xx.xx.xx` command.

Comment: Apologies. I forgot to include the port in ssh-keyscan. It is 
```ssh-keyscan -t rsa,ecdsa -p 22000 192.34.186.186 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts```.
The known hosts file looks like this:
```[193.34.186.186]:22000 ssh-rsa AAAA.......verylongkey```
There are few other keys in it as well but this is the one for this host I'm trying to ssh into

Comment: Please do not post information in comments. Edit everything into your question (including full public key)